# Need syntax for executing msdeploy commands on remote host using github actions

Tags: batch-file, syntax-error, escaping, github-actions, webdeploy

I wish to use msdeploy utility to run the below couple of commands on remotehost windows github runner using cmd shell (or powershell whichever will do)

`cd  C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\qa` and then
`C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\pm2.cmd restart Signup-qa`

Attempt 1:

```
env:
  msdeployPath: 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe'
  myvalue_deploy_path: "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\qa\"
  myvalue_app_name: Signup-qa
  myvalue_serverlist: remotehost

on:

  push:
    branches:
      - "*"

jobs:

  SETVARS:
    environment: DEPLOYPASS

    runs-on: 'windows-latest'
    steps:

      - name: Execute command on remote host
        run: |
          "& cmd /c ${{ env.msdeployPath }} -verb:sync -source:runcommand -dest:runcommand=cd \"${{ env.myvalue_deploy_path }}\"; \"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\pm2.cmd\" restart ${{ env.myvalue_app_name }}\",waitinterval=200000,wmsvc='https://${{ env.myvalue_serverlist }}:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=BackupSite',AuthType=Basic,userName=DeployDev,password='mypass' -allowUntrusted -verbose'"
```

Error:

```
Run "& cmd /c C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:runcommand -dest:runcommand=cd \"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\qa\"; \"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\pm2.cmd\" restart Signup-qa\",waitinterval=200000,wmsvc='https://remotehost:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=BackupSite',AuthType=Basic,userName=DeployDev,password='***' -allowUntrusted -verbose'"

ParserError: D:\Github Runners\mmx-action-runner-1\_work\_temp\d1efc2c5-a2da-4a05-a914-01d56e9f876c.ps1:3

Line |

   3 |  … ncommand=cd \"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\qa\"; \"C:\\Program Files\\ …

     |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

     | Unexpected token 'C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\qa\"; \"C:\\Program' in expression or statement.

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I then decided to simplify things by creating a batch file `controlpm2.bat` and passing arguments to it and then invoking the same batch from `ms-deploy` like below:

Attempt 2:

```
  - name: Execute command on remote host
    run: |
      cmd /c "${{ env.msdeployPath }} -verb:sync -source:runcommand -dest:runcommand=\"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\controlpm2.bat ${{ env.myvalue_deploy_path }} stop ${{ env.myvalue_app_name }}\" -waitinterval=200000 -wmsvc=\"https://${{ env.myvalue_serverlist }}:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=BackupSite\" -allowUntrusted -verbose -AuthType:Basic -userName:DeployDev -password:'mypass'"
```

Error:

```
  cmd /c "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:runcommand -dest:runcommand=\"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\controlpm2.bat C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\qa stop Signup-qa\" -waitinterval=200000 -wmsvc=\"https://remotehost:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=BackupSite\" -allowUntrusted -verbose -AuthType:Basic -userName:DeployDev -password:'***'"    

  shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'" 

'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

cat controlpm2.bat

```
echo off
set deploy_path=%1
set action=%2
set app_name=%3

cd %deploy_path%
"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\pm2.cmd" %action% %app_name%
```

I tried other options too like referring pm2.cmd as  `%SystemDrive%\Progra~1\nodejs\pm2.cmd` but that too did not help.

Can someone please suggest?